# How to display No data Found in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a site and I have put the all data in the table of that site. Now I want to implement a search where user can easily search the data so I have successfully created  search function but the problem is that when there is no data related to search data then it will display a blank screen in that time I want to display "NO DATA FOUND" I don't how I can do that can anyone help me?
my searching script

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.search').on('keyup',function(){
        var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $('#userTbl tbody tr').each(function(){
            var lineStr = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            if(lineStr.indexOf(searchTerm) === -1){
                $(this).hide();
            }else{
                $(this).show();
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This might be helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284270/how-to-display-no-records-found-message-for-div-search-on-keyup

Answer (score 2):

Keep an element in your page like this: `<div id="not-found">no results</div>`.
And use the same idea from `.show()/.hide()` in order to become your element visible or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use if condition, if search= 0 then write no data found.

Comment: Your answer would be more useful if you could show how your suggestion fits in with the OP's code.